# How to change seo friendly URL in php with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to change SEO friendly URL in PHP with htaccess. I facing error SEO url, Please help me find a solution.How to convert SEO friendly URL in core PHP in pagination.Creating Search Engine Friendly URLs with PHP show the current output url

```
Current url output
domain.com/listpage.php?page=8

Required url output
domain.com/listpage.php/page/8

 Current code

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule  ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^listpage/([0-9]+)$ listpage?page=$1
 RewriteRule ^listpage/([0-9]+)/$ listpage?page=$1



<html>
<head>
<title>Paging Next Previous Buttons</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include('conn.php');
$rowsPerPage = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$pageNum= $_GET['page'];
}
else
$pageNum = 1;
// preceding rows
$previousRows =($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
// the first, optional value of LIMIT is the start position
//the next required value is the number of rows to retrieve
$query = "select * from tablename WHERE status = '1' LIMIT $previousRows, $rowsPerPage";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error couldn\'t get the data').mysql_error();
echo "<table border=1>\n";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Password</th><th>Perm</th><th>Email</th>
<th>Date</th></tr>";
// print the results

 //$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                { ?>


<tr><td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['titlename']; ?></td></tr>
<?php 
}

echo '</table>';
// Find the number of rows in the query
$query = "SELECT COUNT(titlename) AS numrows FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, couldn\'t get count title=\"$page\"').mysql_error();
//use an associative array
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];
// find the last page number
$lastPage = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);
//we use ceil which rounds up the result, because if we have 4.2 as an answer, we'd need 5 pages.
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
//if the current page is greater than 1, that is, it isn't the first page
//then we print first and previous links
if ($pageNum > 1){
$page = $pageNum - 1;
$prev = " <a href=\"$phpself/page/$page\" title=\"Page $page\">[Back]</a> ";
$first = " <a href=\"$phpself/page/1\" title=\"Page 1\">[First Page]</a> ";
}
else
//otherwise we do not print a link, because the current page is
//the first page, and there are no previous pages
{
$prev = ' [Back] ';
$first = ' [First Page] ';
}
// We print the links for the next and last page only if the current page
//isn't the last page
if ($pageNum < $lastPage)
{
$page = $pageNum + 1;
$next = " <a href=\"$phpself/page/$page\" title=\"Page $page\">[Next]</a> ";
$last = " <a href=\"$phpself/page/$lastPage\" title=\"Page $lastPage\">[Last Page]</a> ";
}
//the current page is the last page, so we don't print links for
//the last and next pages, there is of course no next page.
else
{
$next = ' [Next] ';
$last = ' [Last Page] ';
}
//We print the links depending on our selections above
echo $first . $prev . " Showing page <bold>$pageNum</bold> of
<bold>$lastPage</bold> pages " . $next . $last;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using a routing component like the symfony router instead of hacking at htaccess. Installable via composer. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/listpage.php/page/(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /listpage.php?page=8 [L]

should work not tested

Comment: Now This error show
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request